# Is there a better way to assert that all intercepted requests are successful in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to test that all 12 requests involved in creating an object are successful, so far this is the only way I can figure out that works. IS there a better/more efficient/more flexible way that won't break as soon as we add or remove a request?

```
              cy.intercept('/api/**/**').as('objectCreation');
              $button.click();

              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
              cy.wait('@objectCreation').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll like more details about your question:

- Are the requests identical?

However, to answer your question on how to simplify your shared, code snippet...you could create a `variable` representing the `request` creation attempts & keep calling the `cy.intercept()` method & asserting its `response` until you hit the specified request creation amount like so:

```js
const reqObjCreationNum = 0; // reqObjCreationNum object creation attempts number

/**
 * @param {number} reqObjCreationNum - number of object creation attempts
 */
const createObject = ({ reqObjCreationNum }) => {
  cy.intercept('/api/**/**').as('objectCreation');

  while (reqObjCreationNum <= 12) {
    cy.wait('@objectCreation')
      .its('response.statusCode')
      .should('eq', 200);

    reqObjCreationNum += 1;
  }
};

createObject({ reqObjCreationNum });
```

I would suggest the [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#:%7E:text=%22Don%27t%20repeat%20yourself%22,data%20normalization%20to%20avoid%20redundancy.) programming concept as a future reading.

Comment: The requests aren't identical, however, it turns out I was misunderstanding the nature of the requests, and don't need to assert on all of them like I thought. I'll remember this in case I need it in the future though, thank you!